# Undefined variable en Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, blade

compañeros estoy teniendo en el siguiente problema y no logro dar con la solucion, tengo una vista con un form para realizar el alta de un usuario, el cual tiene el siguiente dropdownlist

```
<select class="form-control" name="department_id" id="department_id">
@foreach($departments as $department)
   <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{ $department->descripcion}}</option>
 @endforeach
 </select>
```

codigo que funciona, ya que se carga el contenido al select y llamo a la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
public function create(){
    $departments = Department::all();
    $locations = Location::all();
    return view('create')->with(compact('departments','locations'));
}
```

Ahora bien, cuando hago el submit para realizar el alta obtengo **Undefined variable: departments (View: ...\resources\views\create.blade.php)**

Por que me dice que DEPARTMENTS no esta definido en esa vista si los datos se cargan al select correctamente? el problema surge cuando oprimo en el boton enviar y quiero realizar el POST para hacer el alta.. no logro descubrir el problema

Edit: agrego funcion de store en el controlador

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $user = $request->all();
    $user['password'] = Hash::make($user['password']);
    User::create($user);
    return view('create')->with('exito','Usuario dado de alta correctamente');
}
```

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de los modelos?

Comment: class Department extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'descripcion',
    ];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','location_id','department_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     *
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}

Comment: No se si se entiende! Lo raro es que el codigo es similar para editar y funciona perfecto, y la variable departments se la paso a la vista al llamar, nose porque surge el problema solo al hacer el submit

Comment: como tienes la funcion que guarda en la base de datos?, pon mas codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Deberias colocar el codigo del controlador donde procesas la logica del alta de usuario. Para verificar el problema @Marcelo

Comment: @GustavoHerrera ahi añadi la funcion, saludos

Comment: @KevinBurbano ahi la agregue al post, saludos!

Comment: en el método `store` estás devolviendo la vista `create` que hace uso de la variable `departments` pero en ese método no informas esa variable

Comment: Toda la razon @JaviMollá !! muchisimas gracias, no me habia dado cuenta!

Answer (score 1):

Estas Utilizando la misma vista tanto para Create como para Store, por lo tanto es normal que espere los valores que enviarías desde el Create cuando retornas desde Store.

Ahora bien, no se como es tu vista, o lógica de porque eso asi, pero veo 2 opciones básicas y otra un poco mas trabajada.

- Creas una vista para cada función (una para Create y otra para Store).
- Creas condicionales para comprobar si existe $exito, y de existir no haces la parte del llenado de los select (algo asi).

```
    @isset($departments)
     @foreach($departments as $department)
       id}}">{{ $department->descripcion}}
     @endforeach
    @endisset
```

- Envias: $departments y $locations en la de Store.

Ahora, depende de si quieres permitir modificar (lo cual no seria lo mejor ya que estas en respuesta de store) lo que puedes hacer es enviar esas dos variables con todos los valores y hacer un condicional, que te indique si existe la variable $exito entonces el formulario se enviaría a update (no recomendaría mucho esto, porque luego te llevaras estos problemas contigo al update normal, pero para programación con ajax si tiene mucho mas sentido y uso).

Si lo que quieres es utilizar los select para mostrar el valor que introdujo y quedo guardado en Base de datos, puedes enviar dichos valores en las variables y utilizar $exito para volver disable u onlyread el select, algo como:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="department_id" id="department_id" {{ isset($exito) ? 'disabled' : '' }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

claro que tienes un error, no puedes combinar ambas formas de envio solo usar uno de ellos, y ya tendras las variables disponibles en las vistas

**por with**

```
public function create(){
    $departments = Department::all();
    $locations = Location::all();
    return view('create')
                ->with('departments',$departments)
                ->with('locations',$locations);
}
```

**por compact**

```
public function create(){
    $departments = Department::all();
    $locations = Location::all();
    return view('create',compact('departments','locations'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La vista create.blade.php está claro que espera como mínimo la variable 'departments' y 'locations'. Cuando es llamada desde la función create no obtienes error porque en la llamada a la vista, pasas estas variables con 'compact'. Pero al hacer submit, es la función store la que llama a la vista create, y en este caso sólo pasas la variable 'exito', **por eso obtienes ese error**.

Debes asegurarte de que cuando la vista create es cargada, si viene desde la función store, no haga el @foreach

Un saludo.